# ARGB8888 poor quality

Tags: android, drawable, argb

I tried to add text to a `drawable`, but the only way I found was to make text into a bitmap and use `layerdrawable`. I tried the following code :

```
Bitmap canvasBitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(sb.getWidth(), sb.getHeight(), Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
Canvas imageCanvas = new Canvas(canvasBitmap);
imageCanvas.drawARGB(0, 0, 0, 0);
Paint p = new Paint();
p.setColor(Color.WHITE);
p.setTextSize(40);
imageCanvas.drawText("Sample text display here", 0, sb.getHeight()/2, p);
LayerDrawable background = new LayerDrawable(new Drawable[]{new BitmapDrawable(canvasBitmap)});
```

But the quality is poor compared to the other text fields.

I need a suggestion on how to either improve quality of the text or another way to add text to a `drawable`.

Comment: Have you tried using a Drawable as the background for a TextView? What does "poor" mean in this context? Too big, too small, too fuzzy, too Comic Sans-y?

Comment: i think pixelated is the word. like when you set a low resolution image as wallpaper.

Comment: And have you tried a TextView with a background drawable?